# Printing vb.net forms with a loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops, printing

Hi I am tring print multiple copies of box labels that are on a form using vb.net

the copies will depent on the amount of boxes on the job and will range from 1 to 500 copies.
I would like to print these but also print a choosen box number if required. 
Can any one help as all my attempts have failed.

The problem is it captures the screen including msgboxs of what is currenting being printed or done and calls them all document 1. Is there a simple way to print without screen capture.

here is my code at the moment

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing


Public Class print

    Inherits Form
    Private WithEvents printButton As New Button
    Private WithEvents printDocument1 As New PrintDocument


    Dim memoryImage As Bitmap

    Private Sub CaptureScreen()
        Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        Dim s As Size = Me.Size
        memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics)
        Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, s)
    End Sub

    Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles _
       printDocument1.PrintPage
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0)
    End Sub

 Private Sub printButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles printButton.Click
Dim numberofboxes As Integer = 3
Dim startbox As Integer = 1
Dim counter As Integer = 1
For index As Integer = startbox To numberofboxes
    CaptureScreen()
    printDocument1.Print()
    lblFirstBoxPrint.Text = counter
    counter = counter + 1
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = True
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\test '" & counter & "'.xps"
    printDocument1.Print()
Next
End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New print())
    End Sub

    Private Sub print_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        printButton.Text = "Print Form"
        Me.Controls.Add(printButton)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to actually print your form, as it appears on screen, consider the built-in [PrintForm Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690938.aspx). After adding the component, and setting properties, printing is a one line process.

```
 PrintForm1.Print()
```

See this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629268(v=vs.90).aspx) for further details.